# customize windows 7 profile in domain

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

I'm having trouble understanding the process to customize the default profile.
how can i make certain changes that can only be made while the computer is member of a domain and copy it later to the default profile (the local administrator)

specifically- i want to install a printer while logged in to the domain and make it part of the default profile.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sysprep will remove the system from the domain and remove the SID information, so you can’t do this in the way you described. [This KB article talks about it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023766). There are alternate methods to get this done, however.

1. You could script this to happen after deployment of the image using the SetupComplete.cmd file ([see this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/1c250d8e-995c-4b3e-8199-3a0acad095ca/)
2. Use [Group Policy to deploy a printer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722179(v=WS.10).aspx)
3. If you use MDT to deploy your Operating Systems, you can run ‘Post-installation’ tasks to do this for you after Windows is installed, but still during the deployment process (this is also done by script).
4. Logon script (See the thread linked in #1 for a PowerShell example).